# JS - get array in an object by value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object `game = {};` and I save an array with two id's under every number of the object - `game[number] = [id1, id2];` e.g. `game[0] = [234342, 134313]`.
How can I get the number of the object `game[number]` by only ONE id of the array `[id1, id2]`? Obviously every id is only used once in the whole object.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: why not use an array? or better why do you use an object if you use an array structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this? for each item in object, for each item in array of ids, look for our id.

```
var game = {
    1:[123,345],
    2:[124,456],
    3:[125,567]
}

function find(findId) {
    var returnId = 0;
    for(var id in game) { 
        console.log(game[id]); 
        for (var i = 0; i < game[id].length; i++) {
            if (game[id][i] == findId) {
                returnId = id;
            }
        }
    }
    return returnId;
}

console.log(find(124));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) with the possibillity of short circuit if the id is found.

```js
var game = { 1: [123, 345], 2: [124, 456], 3: [125, 567] },
    ids = function (id, data) {
        var r;
        Object.keys(data).some(function (k) {
            return data[k].some(function (a) {
                if (id === a) {
                    r = data[k];
                    return true;
                }
            });
        });
        return r;
    }(456, game);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(ids, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var game, id, k, val;
game = {
  1: ['aa', 'ab'],
  2: ['ba', 'bb']
};
find_game = function(id, data) {
  for (k in game) {
    for (val in game[k]) {
      if (id === game[k][val]) {
        return k
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Improve your answer with output raw.

Answer (score 1):

```
var game = { '0': [ 234342, 134313 ],
  '1': [ 23434, 13431 ],
  '2': [ 23432, 13433 ] }

var i
var id = 23432;
for (i in game){
    if (game[i].indexOf(id) > -1){
        console.log(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

---

Or  function based approach

```
var game = { '0': [ 234342, 134313 ],
  '1': [ 23434, 13431 ],
  '2': [ 23432, 13433 ] }

function getNumber(id, game){
  var i
  for (i in game){
    if (game[i].indexOf(id) > -1){
        return i;
    }
  }
}

var id = 23432;
var number = getNumber(id, game)
console.log(number);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` and `reduce` for that

```
function findIt(game, theId){
  return Object.keys(game).filter(function(index){
    return game[index].reduce((a, b) => (a == theId || b == theId));
  })[0];
}

findIt(game, 444);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are anyways using an object. Use your id's array as key. Use something like this, `game[[id1,id2]] = number`. This shall give you a faster lookup because, JS objects are hash data structures. Your method gives O(n) lookup, while hash objects are generally meant to give O(logn) time.